# SwiftUI Localization one string is not getting translated

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode13

I have this one string word "Every " which is stored like below that doesn't get translated.

```
        ForEach(viewModel.repeatTimes, id: \.self) { repeatedDay in
            Button(action: {
                if repeatTime.contains(repeatedDay) {
                    repeatTime.removeAll(where: { repeatedDay == $0 })
                } else {
                    repeatTime.append(repeatedDay)
                }
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Text("Every " + repeatedDay.day)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    Spacer()
                    if repeatTime.contains(repeatedDay) {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

While buttons, navigation titles other Text objects get translated without problems I can't get this to translate. In my localized.strings file this is how it is accessed.

`"Every " = "Every ";`

I've even tried deleting the whole file and copy pasting the strings so there wouldn't be any typo but still I can't get this to work and don't know what I am missing.

This is how app looks like on a simulator translated to Turkish

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change `Text("Every " + repeatedDay.day)` to `Text("Every ") + Text(repeatedDay.day)`

Comment: This won't work because the String is put together and then translated. You have to get the localization for it independently

Answer (score 1):

you could try this, or a combination of such (as per @jnpdx suggestion):

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey("Every " + repeatedDay.day))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer unfortunately this doesn't work Text is already localized I believe the problem is when you add a variable to Text it messes up the localization.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for a solution @jnpdx however .foreground color wasn't working so I just changed it to this.

```
HStack {
Text("Every")
    .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
Text(repeatedDay.day)
    .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
}
```

Edit: A better way to do this:

```
HStack {
  Text("Every \(repeatedDay.day)")
     .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
}
```

in the localized.strings file:

```
"Every %@" = "Every %@"; // for EN
"Every %@" = "Her %@"; // for TR
```

since HStack adds it's own spacing it might cause some issues with localized string parameter '%@' it's much simpler and cleaner/